# MongoDB starting gets terminating

Tags: linux, file-permissions, mongodb, user-permissions

I am installing the mongodb with the default configurations, and that gets started normally, but when I changed the **dbpath** value to point to different position it started giving me the exceptions, can some one help me and tell me where I am doing the mistake,

Here is my **/etc/mongod.conf** file that is I am changing,

[image]

Here is what I getting the output when trying to start the mongodb

[image]

Here is my mongodb logs from **/var/log/mongo/mongod.log**

[image]

here is my **/ebs/mongo/** and **/ebs/mongo/db** permissions

[image]

here is strace of **service start mongod** (its pretty big :( )

[strace -f service mongod start > test.txt](https://db.tt/hsZjJ5M3)

I have really no clue what is going on here
:(,
please shed some light...
Thanks in advance

Comment: By any chance, your mongod service does not run as root, does it ? Look into /etc/init/mongod.conf and show us the money :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `db` folder is owned by `root:root` and you should not be running MongoDB as `root`.  If you are using the MongoDB defaults (you don't mention what flavor of Linux you are using), then the service will either start as the `mongod` or `mongodb` user, not `root`, which is the correct behavior.

Hence, when the `mongod` process tries to create/use the `mongod.lock` file you get a permissions error.  You need to change the permissions of `/ebs/mongo/db` appropriately.  That can be done with one of the following commands (as `root`, or with sudo):

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /ebs/mongo/db
```

Or:

```
chown -R mongod:mongod /ebs/mongo/db
```

You will also want to make sure that whatever `logpath` you use can be written by the same user.  I've basically answered this one [before on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232668/1148648) with a slightly different cause, so have a look there also.